# Can I memoize the result of a function that calls useState?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a function, `foo`, that calls `useState` several times.  It generally looks like this:

```
const foo = () => {
  const [state1, setState1] = useState(...)
  const [state2, setState2] = useState(...)

  const fn1 = () => {
    // do some stuff, fetch some data, modify state
  }
  const fn2 = () => {
    // do some stuff, fetch some data, modify state
  }

  return {
    state1,
    state2,
    fn1,
    fn2
  }
}
```

This function returns an object containing several methods and several variables.

I have a component that does something like:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const myFoo = foo()
  foo.fn1()
  console.log(foo.state1)

  return (...)
}
```

Since `const myFoo = ...` is top level, `foo()` is executed on every re-render.

I want to memoize `myFoo` but I get warnings about not calling Hooks inside `useEffect` or `useMemo` if I try to put it in `useState` or `useMemo`.

Conceptually speaking, am I at a dead end architecturally?  Is there any way to memoize the results of a function call when that function call involves `useState`?  Is it improper to have a non-custom-hook that calls `useState` (i.e. should `foo` really be something like `useFoo`)?  Even then, how could I memoize the results of a custom hook?

Thanks.

Comment: if it is returning an object then why can't you use `useMemo` instead of `useState`

Comment: If the function, the `foo`, is not a component, then why are you using `useState` inside of it ? That is a big no-no.

Comment: Some actual (commented) code showing your problem might be more useful here, it's not super clear what you're trying to do and where specifically the issue is arising. We can speculate, but it's easier for you to just add the relevant code

Comment: @DecPK I am getting warnings when using `useMemo` _and_ `useState` - so I'm wondering if I can use either.

Comment: @Jayce444 added some pseudocode example

Comment: Re: "Is it improper to have a non-custom-hook that calls `useState` (i.e. should `foo` really be something like `useFoo`)?": Correct: hooks should only be called from components and from custom hooks. See https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning for more information.